# S3 java SDK - set expiry to object

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a file to S3 and set an expire date for it using Java SDK.

This is the code i got:

```
   Instant expiration = Instant.now().plus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setExpirationTime(Date.from(expiration));
            metadata.setHeader("Expires", Date.from(expiration));
            s3Client.putObject(bucketName, keyName, new FileInputStream(file), metadata);
```

The object has no expire data on it in the S3 console.

What can I do?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: you are not allowed to set an expiry date for single object, you should set a lifecycle rule for bucket (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

These are two unrelated things.  The expiration time shown in the console is `x-amz-expiration`, which is populated by the system, by lifecycle policies.  It is read-only.

> **`x-amz-expiration`**
>
> Amazon S3 will return this header if an Expiration action is configured for the object as part of the bucket's lifecycle configuration.  The header value includes an "expiry-date" component and a URL-encoded "rule-id" component.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html

`Expires` is a header which, when set on an object, is returned in the response when the object is downloaded.

> **`Expires`**
>
> The date and time at which the object is no longer able to be cached. For more information, go to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

It isn't possible to tell S3 when to expire (delete) a specific object -- this is only done as part of bucket lifecycle policies, as described in the User Guide under [Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation the method [**setExpirationTime()**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setExpirationTime-java.util.Date-) using for internal needs and do not define **expiration time** for the uploaded object

> public void setExpirationTime(Date expirationTime)
>
> For internal use only. This will *not* set the object's expiration
> time, and is only used to set the value in the object after receiving
> the value in a response from S3.

So you can’t directly set expiration date for particular object. To solve this problem you can:

1. Define lifecycle rule for a bucket(remove bucket with objects after number of days)
2. Define lifecycle rule for bucket level to remove objects with specific tag or prefix after numbers of days

To define those rules use documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html